# Mapping NFS mount with docker: "Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path"

Tags: docker, nfs

I'm trying to run a docker that gets its data from an NFS mount, something in the trend of:

`docker -v /mnt/nfs1:/input ...`

but I'm getting errors like:

> docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/mnt/nfs1/input/large_files/quickstart-output': mkdir /mnt/nfs1/input: permission denied.

The NFS mount point is mounted as a non-root user and has root-squash set on the server config. I can't change this.

Also adding `--user 12345` has had no effect.

Also trying to mount the NFS as that user from within the docker didn't work probably because the IP wasn't the same as the allowed one (?)

Can anybody let me know if it's possible and if so, how I can fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I solved it.. something along the lines of:

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs \
  --opt o=addr=nfs.server.com,ro --opt device=:/complete/path nfs_input
    
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs \
  --opt o=addr=nfs.server.com,rw --opt device=:/other/complete/path nfs_output
    
docker run \
  --user 12345:12345 \
  --mount source=nfs_input,target=/input \
  --mount source=nfs_output,target=/output \
  my_docker_image ....
```